# Facing issue in gitlab login for the last 1 hour

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to log in for the last 1 hour but am stuck in a cached problem. I can't log in to GitLab.

[image]

Comment: Didi you try refreshing with `shitf-F5` (or click on `shit+refresh-button`)

Comment: Try `Ctrl + F5` to make your browser skip its cache and try to reload the page. If you still have this, check your proxy setup if you know you go through one.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
I tried these 3 methods but the same issue.

Comment: @LeGEC How I can check proxy setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this issue occurs if your time is not set accurate on your machine.

Try **set your PC time accurate**, and issue will be resolved.